# qt5 webkit undefined reference to `QWebView::load`

Tags: c++, qt, webkit, qt5

I include my header files:

```
 #include <QtWebkit>
 #include <QtWebkit/QWebView>
 #include <QUrl>
```

and add to the `.pro` file `QT+=webkit`

but `Qt` throw error:

> undefined reference to      `QWebView::load(QUrl const&)`

I don't know why `QWebView` doesn't work.

```
ui->webView->load(QUrl("http://google.com"));
```

and I use `Fedora 21 64 bit`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In `Qt5` you need

```
QT += webkitwidgets
```

in `.pro` file, not `QT+=webkit`

[For more details.](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwebview.html)

```
Header: #include <QWebView>  
qmake:   QT += webkitwidgets
```